# Twitter Bootstrap isn't aligning propertly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if it's a bug or some mistake of mine.
In my Rails project, twitter's bootstrap isn't aligning the container at the center.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span12" style="background-color:blue; color:white;">
        <%= yield %> <!-- This get the sample text "Some test." -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an image of the bug.
http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/3405/screenshot20120702at035.png

Thanks a lot everybody! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/kLFSC/1)